# using jquery to hide and show elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I have a webpage with a form for posting comments( a textfield and a textarea + submit button).I wanted the form to be invisible at first and show only a 'showform' link to make the form visible as well as to show the 'hideform' link.When 'hideform' link is clicked ,the form & the `hideform link` should be made invisible ,and the showform link should be made visible again.
I tried this

```
<html>
<head>
<title>formopen demo</title>
<link href="formopen.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<script src="jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script src="formopen.js"></script>


<body>
<div class="myjsdemo">
   <a href="#" class="showaddcommentformlink">show add commentform</a>
   <a href="#" class="hideaddcommentformlink">hide add commentform</a>
   <div class="form">
      <input type="text" value="" name="myinput" id="myinput"/>
      <textarea name="content" rows="2" cols="20" id="content" > </textarea>
   </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

formopen.css

```
.myjsdemo .form{display:none;}
.myjsdemo .hideaddcommentformlink{display:none;}
```

formopen.js

```
$(function(){
    $('.myjsdemo.showaddcommentformlink').click(
      function(){
            $(this).hide();
            $('.myjsdemo.hideaddcommentformlink').show();
            $('.myjsdemo.form').show();
            return false;
        }
    );

    $('.myjsdemo.hideaddcommentformlink').click(
      function(){
            $(this).hide();
            $('.myjsdemo.showaddcommentformlink').show();
            $('.myjsdemo.form').hide();
            return false;
        }
    );

});
```

However nothing happens when I click on the link...I have very minimal knowledge of javascript ..If someone can correct any mistakes in this code ,it would be a great help..

I am putting all files in the same directory and opening the html file in firefox.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add a space between the CSS classes.

```
.myjsdemo.showaddcommentformlink
```

Should be

```
.myjsdemo .showaddcommentformlink
```

And so on. Otherwise jQuery will grab elements that have both the classes applied at the same time.

The final function should be like this one:

```
$(function(){
    $('.myjsdemo .showaddcommentformlink').click(
      function(){
            $(this).hide();
            $('.myjsdemo .hideaddcommentformlink').show();
            $('.myjsdemo .form').show();
            return false;
        }
    );

    $('.myjsdemo .hideaddcommentformlink').click(
      function(){
            $(this).hide();
            $('.myjsdemo .showaddcommentformlink').show();
            $('.myjsdemo .form').hide();
            return false;
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your selectors are wrong. They should be:

```
$('.myjsdemo .showaddcommentformlink')
```

and

```
$('.myjsdemo .hideaddcommentformlink')
```

and

```
$('.myjsdemo .form')
```

using them in the `.selector.another` form, you are targetting elements with both classes.

i.e:

```
<span class="myjsdemo form">
```

when you add an space, you are targetting elements with the selector after the space, that are contained by elements with the selector before the space.

i.e:

elements with the class "form" that are contained by elements with the class "myjsdemo"

Answer (score 2):

Your selectors are wrong, see http://jsfiddle.net/j9Zy4/ for a working version of your code.